# Error creating a dash table with a column containing buttons with links to download a file

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have created a dash application in which you need to add a tab with a table. there is no problem in this. the problem is that I can create a table with data like: int, str, bool. however, I have a column with a link for which I need to create an additional column with a button to download (upload) a log file from this link. here is my code:

```
data = {'Time': dates, 'Strategy': strategies, 'Job': jobs, 'Status': statuses, 'Link to log': logs}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def render_download_link(link):
    return html.A('Download log', href=link, target='_blank')
df['Download_log'] = df['Link to log'].apply(render_download_link)
layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        columns=[
            {'name': 'Time', 'id': 'Time'},
            {'name': 'Strategy', 'id': 'Strategy'},
            {'name': 'Job', 'id': 'Job'},
            {'name': 'Status', 'id': 'Status'},
            {'name': 'Link to log', 'id': 'Link'},
            {'name': '', 'id': 'Download_log', 'presentation': 'markdown'}
        ],
        style_data_conditional=[
                {
                    'if': {'column_id': 'Download_log'},
                    'textAlign': 'center'
                }
            ]
    )
])
```

however, when loading the application, an error of incorrect data format is displayed and the application does not work. please tell me what options there are. thanks